# SharePoint Manager for SP13/16?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Anyone have instruction on how to get SPM working on a sp13/16 farm?

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spm

I'm not finding an .exe and the solution is failing to load in Visual Studio.

The exe can be found here:
https://github.com/chrisdee/Tools/tree/a05f9486e63fd30a03060ee47c8c07a69e44e8a9/SharePoint/SharePointManager/SharePointManager2013

Comment: You can get the 2013 version here: https://github.com/keutmann/SPM/releases. Should work with 2016, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the SPM 2013 exe here:
https://github.com/chrisdee/Tools/tree/a05f9486e63fd30a03060ee47c8c07a69e44e8a9/SharePoint/SharePointManager/SharePointManager2013

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The question has been resolved. @LisaChenMSFT